# Properties behind an if statement within vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar

Sometimes I don't want to have a "rules" option/property in some input fields, is it possible within vuejs3 to set up a kind of if statement so that the property "rules" are only presented on certain fields? Because now i just do an empty array[]. But would rather see this differently.
So that I dont need to apply "rules" option in my form scheme when I dont need it.

This is my template code:

```
 <div v-for="(prop, key) in formSchema" :key="key">
      
      <q-input v-if="prop.component === 'input'"
         outlined
         v-model="dataRef[key]"
         :type="prop.type"
         :label="prop.label"
         maxlength="12"
         class="super-small"
         hint="Name and surname"
         lazy-rules
         :rules="prop.rules" (want this behind an if statement if not needed)
       >
      </q-input>
    
      <q-select v-else-if="prop.component === 'select'"
        outlined
        v-model="dataRef[key]"
        :type="prop.type"
        :options="prop.options"
        :label="prop.label">
      </q-select>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: you can pass a computed property to `:rules` that either returns the rules, or not, depending on the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ternary condition within your attribute. When the attribute is set to `null` or `undefined` it gets omitted.

`:rules="addRule ? prop.rules : null"`